# Laravel relationships changing table columns makes undefined property

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I changed the name of a column in my Laravel app and the party started..

The change was from name_id to seller_id

Before in view:

```
$transaction->user->first_name
```

Before in controller Transaction:

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
 }
```

After and before in controller calling the view:

```
public function getInfoUser($name){

   $user = User::where('register_id', $name)->where('id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

   if($user){
   return view('users.user', compact('user'));
   }
}
```

After in view:

```
$transaction->seller->first_name
```

After in controller Transaction:

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'seller_id';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

After returns:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/tronne/Documents/web/resources/views/users/user.blade.php) in c7128907204dffe6676c7d88cbbc47.php (line 108) 
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 0) in
PhpEngine.php (line 45)
at PhpEngine-evaluatePath('/Users/tronne/Documents/web/storage/framework/views/c7128907204dffe6676c7d88cbbc47.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'user' => object(User)))
in CompilerEngine.php (line 59)
at CompilerEngine-get('/Users/tronne/Documents/web/resources/views/users/user.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'user' => object(User)))
in View.php (line 137)
```

For reference the table users has the standard column name "user_id" and "first_name" and  the table transactions (transactions controller) now has "seller_id"

Not sure if it affects, but in the SQL table, the primary keys are in both cases "id" autoincrement

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please add the full error

Comment: protected $table = "users";   @Sohel0415 the error its quiet obvious.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I was trying to understand no-object of what

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I'm in the transactions model, protected $table = "users"; should go to users model right? Here it's assuming correctly that the table name is transactionS

Comment: please add full error and your controller code and your model that others can understand clearly

Comment: @Sohel0415 done

Comment: @TrOnNe Please remove what you have done before, add what you are doing now, your controller code, view code and model with property, fillable and relationship method

Comment: where is your controller code and view code, you are showing controller code for `users.get-info-user.blade` but problem seems on `users.user.blade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `user` relationship in your `Transaction` Model but you're trying to access it as `seller` in your view.

**Change:**

```
$transaction->seller->first_name
```

**To:**

```
$transaction->user->first_name
```

**Or**

You could also change the relationship in your model to `seller`. If that's what you need.

**Finally:**

Display data in the view only if there are records in the relationship.

```
@if(!empty($transaction->user))
        $transaction->user->first_name
@else
        //No users
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! upvoted but same thing.. same error, then there're 2 errors, 1 less ;)

Comment: @TrOnNe You still ge the same error? Please post the full error message

Comment: added, the error is pointing to the line $transaction->seller->first_name

Comment: @TrOnNe The error occurs when there are no users belonging to the relationship. Are you use that particular transaction has users?

Comment: It solves the error but not the problem haha, $transaction->user is the user itself who made the transaction, so is not empty, the problem is that laravel is not finding the $transaction->user because of some problem with the column name

Comment: @TrOnNe try changing         `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');`  to `return $this->belongsTo('App\User','seller_id');`

Comment: nothing.. I tried already before, but same problem, for sure it's a silly error I made, but I can't find it

Comment: I can't figure what else could be causing it. Please recheck the column names and look for any typos.

Comment: I redid everything you said and apparently it solved, something I forgot or something. thank you!

Comment: @TrOnNe Happy coding!